# can I use a constant value in the GROUP BY clause when using COUNT(*) to ensure that it always returns one value in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregation

The output should be similar to the output of this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM my_table
```

But with GROUP BY:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY ?
```

No matter what I will paste instead of -- **?** -- it should always return only one value, even if every value in each row and cell in the table data is different.

The second query (with Group BY) **should always return the number of rows in the table** no matter what, so It should behave similar to the first.

If I have 1000 rows of data --> the output should be 1000.

If I have 1011 rows --> the output should be 1011.

I need this to workaround some subquery problems in Django ORM.
Thanks

Comment: You can use `GROUP BY ()` https://dbfiddle.uk/1mTxxBHO - `GROUP BY (SELECT 1)` is allowed but treats the empty input differently https://dbfiddle.uk/EaqKJcIq

Comment: Why do you want the group by at all?

Comment: I need to construct Django ORM query like this

        comment_count = Comment.objects.filter(
            Q(post_id=OuterRef("pk")) | Q(pk=4)
        ).values("()").annotate(
            count=Count("*")
        ).values("count")

Django does not allow use subqueries without aggregation

Comment: I'd rather ask for a Django solution, instead of an odd Postgresql trick.

Comment: The second query is wrong, there is nothing to GROUP BY when you want to know the total number of records. GROUP BY gives you the number of records for each group. That's a different question.

Comment: I just need this Group By statement because of how Django orm works

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm not sure that `GROUP BY ()` is correct according to ANSI-SQL. Eg SQL Server does not return any rows at all if you use `GROUP BY ()`, the same as `GROUP BY (SELECT 1)` https://dbfiddle.uk/a31QJtVe

Comment: @Charlieface - The spec says "If TE does not immediately contain a <group by clause>, then “GROUP BY ()” is implicit"  https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33791/3690  - Oracle also behaves as Postgres here https://dbfiddle.uk/SqFaOnaX

Comment: Though that QA is all in the context of the `HAVING` clause so "who knows" but "If there are no grouping columns, then the result of the <group by clause> is the grouped table consisting of T as its only group." seems clear